# Extracting I-Frames from MPEG 2

Tags: frame, video-processing, mpeg

I am having to reference MPEG-2 code. My application needs analyze I-frames. Looking at the code I am unable to figure out how exactly this can be done.

Basically I want to extract the first or second I-frame. How do I do that and where do I find the information regarding the frame type?

I would appreciate any direction on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just wrote this answer: [Can you find key frame (I-frame) in h264 video without decoding? i.e. is it in packet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915435/can-you-find-key-frame-i-frame-in-h264-video-without-decoding-i-e-is-it-in-p/8961982#8961982)

which applies to you just as well.

The start code of picture in MPEG2 is `0x00` . 
Further, you can see byte 5 - to identify the picture type.

See here: http://dvd.sourceforge.net/dvdinfo/mpeghdrs.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys,  i got it well